# CMake cannot find variable or directory

Tags: python, c++, cmake

I tried to compile an old codebase. My environments are (as required by the codebase):

- Python 2.7
- CMake 2.8.10.1

The provided CMakeLists.txt looks like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)

project(KOL)

set (EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/bin)
#IF(CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX_INITIALIZED_TO_DEFAULT)
set (CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR})
#ENDIF(CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX_INITIALIZED_TO_DEFAULT)

#check if Eigen exists
find_path(EIGEN_PATH NAMES Eigen PATHS ${EIGEN_DIR} REQUIRED)
if (NOT EIGEN_DIR)
    message(FATAL_ERROR "Eigen is not found, please specify by: -DEIGEN_DIR=<eigen_path>")
endif (NOT EIGEN_DIR)


FILE(GLOB data_files src/data/*.h)
FILE(GLOB loss_files src/loss/*.h)
FILE(GLOB opti_files src/kernel/*.h)
FILE(GLOB comm_files src/common/*.h)

set (data_files ${data_files} 
    src/data/basic_io.cpp 
    )

include_directories(
    ${EIGEN_PATH}
    )

#set (data_files ${datafiles} 
#    src/data/basic_io.cpp 
#    src/data/zlib_io.cpp 
#    src/data/gzip_io.cpp
#    )
source_group("data" FILES ${data_files})
source_group("loss" FILES ${loss_files})
source_group("kernel" FILES ${opti_files})
source_group("common" FILES ${comm_files})

set (SRC_LIST
    ${data_files} ${loss_files} ${opti_files} ${comm_files}
    )

IF(CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX)
    SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wno-write-strings -O2 -s")
ENDIF(CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX)

add_executable(KOL src/Params.cpp src/Params.h 
    src/main.cpp ${SRC_LIST}) 
IF(UNIX)
    target_link_libraries(KOL pthread)
ENDIF(UNIX)

add_executable(Cacher src/data/Cacher.cpp ${data_files})
IF(UNIX)
    target_link_libraries(Cacher pthread)
ENDIF(UNIX)

install(TARGETS KOL Cacher
    DESTINATION .)
```

And my command is: `cmake -EIGEN_DIR=../Eigen -CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS='-std=c++0x -O3' ..`

The error is:

```
loading initial cache file MAKE_CXX_FLAGS=-std=c++0x -O3
CMake Error: Error processing file:MAKE_CXX_FLAGS=-std=c++0x -O3
-- The C compiler identification is Clang 10.0.1
-- The CXX compiler identification is Clang 10.0.1
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:13 (message):
  Eigen is not found, please specify by: -DEIGEN_DIR=<eigen_path>
```

My project structure is like this:

```
--Master
 |--build
 |--Eigen
 |--CMakeLists.txt
```

I ran the command inside of the `build` directory. It kept saying that `EIGEN_PATH` is not defined and `Eigen` is not found.

I tried `` -EIGEN_DIR=`pwd`/../Eigen ``. I also tried to use `-DEIGEN_DIR` but still got the same error. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

To specify a cache variable via the CMake command line, use the `-D` flag before the variable names `EIGEN_DIR` and `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS`. Here is the documentation for the `cmake` command line [options and flags](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html#options). Because this creates **cached** entries, try clearing your CMake cache before running the command, to get rid of any stale paths retained within.

Also, be sure to use **double quotes** `" ... "` when enclosing the flags for the `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` variable:

```
cmake -DEIGEN_DIR=Eigen -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="-std=c++0x -O3" ..
```

Comment: The `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` entry also needs to be prefixed with `-D`, i.e. `-DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS='-std=c++0x -O3'`.

Comment: I tried the command and still didn't work. The error codes are:                               
CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND.
Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files:
EIGEN_PATH

Comment: This likely means you have set the `EIGEN_DIR` path incorrectly. Try setting `EIGEN_DIR` to just `Eigen` since the variable will be interpreted relative to the directory containing the CMakeLists.txt file. To be safe, provide the **full** path in `EIGEN_DIR`. I edited the answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `-DEIGEN_DIR` from command line specifying the folder in Eigen library containing the FindEigen.cmake file (search for it with `find ../Eigen -name "*.CMake").

Be careful, the package name should match exactly (case sensitive):

- the name of the find module or config script (FindPackageName.cmake or PackageNameConfig.cmake)
- in `find_package` call
- the name of the PackageName_DIR

Comment: Sorry, I've just seen that you're not using any find_package call. My answer does not apply. Your problem is related to the `find_path` call. Have you tried giving `-DEIGEN_DIR=..` (the project folder containing your Eigen folder)?